# Deploy to heroku invalid URL repository

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, metabase

I am trying to deploy metabase to Heroku using the button:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?button-url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloads.metabase.com%2Flaunch-heroku.html&template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmetabase%2Fmetabase-deploy

When selecting deploy, the following error message is show:

Error: Archive URL not found.

[image]

Is there additional configuration required?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm also getting this error.